# Unable to send application logs to elasticsearch with fluent bit in docker-compose

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, fluent-bit, efk

I'm trying to run app with **EFK** in docker-compose. App writes logs in **/var/log/containers** directory.
When i checked fluent bit logs it has a error `[error] [input:tail:tail.0] read error, check permissions: /var/log/containers/*.log`.

Looks like app logs are invisible to fluent bit.

**fluent bit log**

```
[2022/01/20 07:57:11] [ info] [storage] version=1.0.3, initializing...
2022-01-20T07:57:11.304007900Z [2022/01/20 07:57:11] [ info] [storage] in-memory
2022-01-20T07:57:11.304040100Z [2022/01/20 07:57:11] [ info] [storage] normal synchronization mode, checksum disabled, max_chunks_up=128
2022-01-20T07:57:11.304052200Z [2022/01/20 07:57:11] [ info] [engine] started (pid=1)
2022-01-20T07:57:11.304061000Z [2022/01/20 07:57:11] [error] [input:tail:tail.0] read error, check permissions: /var/log/containers/*.log
2022-01-20T07:57:11.304068900Z [2022/01/20 07:57:11] [ info] [sp] stream processor started
```

**docker-compose file**

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.3.2
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx256m"
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1g

  kibana:
    image: kibana:7.3.2
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1g
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  app:
    image: "raushandoc/efk-springboot-docker-kubernetes"
    ports:
      - "9898:9898"
    links:
      - fluent-bit
    logging:
      driver: "fluentd"
      options:
        fluentd-address: localhost:24224

  fluent-bit:
    image: fluent/fluent-bit:1.4.3
    command: /fluent-bit/bin/fluent-bit -c /fluent-bit/config/fluent-bit.conf
    container_name: fluent-bit
    ports:
      - "24224:24224"
      - "24224:24224/udp"
    volumes:
      - ./fluent-bit.conf:/fluent-bit/config/fluent-bit.conf
      - ./parsers.conf:/fluent-bit/config/parsers.conf
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 60m
    links:
      - elasticsearch

networks:
  default:
    name: local
```

**fluent-bit.conf**

```
[SERVICE]
    Flush   2
    Log_Level   trace
    Parsers_File parsers.conf

[INPUT]
    Name    tail
    Path    /var/log/containers/*.log
    Tag     docker.*
    Parser  docker

[OUTPUT]
    Name            es
    Match           *
    Host            elasticsearch
    Port            9200
    Logstash_Format On
    Replace_Dots    On
    Retry_Limit     False
```

**parsers.conf**

```
[PARSER]
    Name   apache
    Format regex
    Regex  ^(?<host>[^ ]*) [^ ]* (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^\"]*?)(?: +\S*)?)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)")?$
    Time_Key time
    Time_Format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z

[PARSER]
    Name   apache2
    Format regex
    Regex  ^(?<host>[^ ]*) [^ ]* (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^ ]*) +\S*)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>.*)")?$
    Time_Key time
    Time_Format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z

[PARSER]
    Name   apache_error
    Format regex
    Regex  ^\[[^ ]* (?<time>[^\]]*)\] \[(?<level>[^\]]*)\](?: \[pid (?<pid>[^\]]*)\])?( \[client (?<client>[^\]]*)\])? (?<message>.*)$

[PARSER]
    Name   nginx
    Format regex
    Regex ^(?<remote>[^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^\"]*?)(?: +\S*)?)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)")
    Time_Key time
    Time_Format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z

[PARSER]
    Name   json
    Format json
    Time_Key time
    Time_Format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z

[PARSER]
    Name         docker
    Format       json
    Time_Key     time
    Time_Format  %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L
    Time_Keep    On
    # --
    # Since Fluent Bit v1.2, if you are parsing Docker logs and using
    # the Kubernetes filter, it's not longer required to decode the
    # 'log' key.
    #
    # Command      |  Decoder | Field | Optional Action
    # =============|==================|=================
    #Decode_Field_As    json     log

[PARSER]
    Name        docker-daemon
    Format      regex
    Regex       time="(?<time>[^ ]*)" level=(?<level>[^ ]*) msg="(?<msg>[^ ].*)"
    Time_Key    time
    Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L
    Time_Keep   On

[PARSER]
    Name    kube-custom
    Format  regex
    Regex   (?<tag>[^.]+)?\.?(?<pod_name>[a-z0-9](?:[-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(?:\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*)_(?<namespace_name>[^_]+)_(?<container_name>.+)-(?<docker_id>[a-z0-9]{64})\.log$
```

Comment: When your fluent bit (container) starts is there a volume accessible for the container to access, that has a mount containing the mount path of (/var/log/containers/) ??  I would check that first.